# FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED at upload.getFile with inputPhotoFileLocation

Tags: download, mtproto

Can't get content from method upload.getFile using inputPhotoFileLocation, getting exeption FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED, readed lots of forums but cant get answer
I'm using MTProto client on js

```
this.call('upload.getFile', {
    location: {
        _: 'inputPhotoFileLocation',
        id: message.media.photo.id,
        access_hash: message.media.photo.access_hash,
        file_reference: message.media.photo.file_reference, //tried
            //Buffer.from(message.media.photo.file_reference.toString('hex'), 'hex'),
            //[...message.media.photo.file_reference] and others
        thumb_size: JSON.stringify(message.media.photo.sizes.find(size => size._ == 'photoSizeProgressive'))
    },
    offset: 0,
    limit: 1024 * 1024
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputPhotoFileLocation
You must pass `type` from `message.media.photo.sizes` in the `thumb_size` field
That is, instead of `JSON.stringify(message.media.photo.sizes.find(size => size._ == 'photoSizeProgressive'))` you need to specify `message.media.photo.sizes.find(size => size._ == 'photoSizeProgressive').type`